# Random Article from directory displayed on my HTML or PHP pages. I already know how to do this on an HTML Static page but not randomly

Tags: php, spintax

I'm trying to extract articles from a directory at random and then spin and display. This is for Spintax articles Example:

{Cat|Dog|Monkey|Fish|Lizard} {went to the lake|ate a mouse|jumped in the water}

The directory will have multiple text files. I'm sure that I almost have it!

```
<?php
    function spin($s){
        preg_match('#\{(.+?)\}#is', $s, $m);
        if (empty($m)) 
            return $s;

        $t = $m[1];

        if (strpos($t, '{') !== false) 
        { 
            $t = substr($t, strrpos($t,'{') + 1);
        }

        $parts = explode("|", $t);
        $s = preg_replace("+\{".preg_quote($t)."\}+is",                    
        $parts[array_rand($parts)], $s, 1);

        return spin($s);
    }

    $articles = glob("test/*.txt");
    $file = array_rand($articles);
    $string = file_get_contents($articles[$file]);  
    $f = file_get_contents($string, "r");
    while ($line = fgets($f, 1000)) {
       echo spin($line);
    }
?>
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: what is in txt file? $f = file_get_contents($string, "r") .... ?  fopen()

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this 20 mins after.  I posted a none working Script above.

$f = file_get_contents($string, "r"); $string did not belong, I was a bit tired.

```
  <?php


  function spin($s){
  preg_match('#\{(.+?)\}#is',$s,$m);
  if(empty($m)) return $s;

  $t = $m[1];

  if(strpos($t,'{')!==false){
   $t = substr($t, strrpos($t,'{') + 1);
     }

     $parts = explode("|", $t);
     $s = preg_replace("+\{".preg_quote($t)."\}+is",                    
      $parts[array_rand($parts)], $s, 1);

              return spin($s);
                  }





                $articles = glob("test/*.txt");
                $files = array_rand($articles);
                 $f = fopen($articles[$files], "r");
                  while ( $line = fgets($f, 1000) ) {
                    echo spin($line);
                      }
                  ?>
```